# What sort of college education is best to become a LEGO designer?

Tags: lego-group

I'm a big fan of LEGO and I would love to know about what kind of college I should apply to so I can get a degree to work with TLG. Also, I was wondering if I wanted to be a LEGO Set creator, would I have to move out of the United States and move to Denmark, or would I be able to work in the United States and create sets?  I'd love to get feedback because I am in 10th grade, and I am going to college soon.

Comment: Related: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/283/how-does-one-get-a-job-as-a-lego-designer

Comment: You should also consider asking this question to Lego directly since they know best what they want and may even have special programs or similar for people like you.

Answer (score 2):

Try for an industrial engineering degree. That would be the best fit for a set designer. An art degree would work too.

If you want to be a LEGO set designer, you're gonna have to move to Denmark. Of course, you need to be accepted first. You can stay where you are while you work on your degree and become more proficient in working with bricks.